# Android App for Bluetooth Qualification Testing (GATT connection, L2CAP channel, RFCOMM channel, OBEX connection, PAN transport)

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, android-bluetooth, android-11, bluetooth-gatt

I am trying to do Bluetooth Qualification testing on my product.
The Hardware of the product that I am working on runs Android 11 os. The software interface is similar to Android Mobile phones. I was able to get through testing for most of the profiles, I am currently stuck with some profiles like OPP, PAN, HOGP, ScPP.

During the testing of these profiles the test requires the DUT/Product to perform more than the basic activities that I am capable of initiating through the basic interface that Android provides. I was wondering if there are android apps which help in testing complex profiles like these.

Some of these activities are Creating RFCOMM or L2CAP channel, Initiate PAN transport, Creating an OBEX connection.
[Popups while running some Bluetooth tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OKyQ.png)

Issue 2: GATT connection issues while testing HOGP and ScPP profiles

I was able to initiate a GATT connection but the test would end up "INCONC" (inconclusive) and not "PASS" because of wrong values in the parameters "HCI-Conn_Interval" and "HCI-Supervision_Timeout". The values expected are in the ranges "0x6 to 0xc80" and "0xa to 0xc80" respectively.
I have attached pictures of output logs and Virtual Snigger error logs.

[Output Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAaN5.png)
[Virtual Snigger Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fUTa.png)

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask]

Comment: @Rob Since Bluetooth is a globally standardised RF technology, I think the question of the necessary test tools is covered by "software tools commonly used by programmers", even if you have never heard of them or used them.

Comment: Only one question at a time.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 1):

[AOSP](https://source.android.com/) provides the [additional tools](https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/bluetooth/verifying_debugging#profile-tuning-suite) to complement the Bluetooth PTS.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Please delete this.

Comment: Why delete an obviously correct answer, especially since the Bluetooth SIG officially states that Stack Overflow is [its own developer forum](https://www.bluetooth.com/develop-with-bluetooth/build/developer-forum/)?

Comment: The question is off topic for the reasons listed in the comments under the question and the one I just gave you. Do not answer off topic questions. [answer]